# Angular + Spring boot Websocket cors error

Tags: angular, spring-boot, websocket, cors

I am developing a websocket locally with Spring boot and Angular 12. I have been reading a lot of tutorials but I am having a weird Cors error.

The Angular code to connect to the socket is the following:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { NotificationWebSocket } from '../model/NotificationWebSocket.model';
import {  Stomp } from '@stomp/stompjs';
import * as SockJS from 'sockjs-client';


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class WebsocketService{

  stompClient: any;
  webSocketEndPoint: string = 'http://localhost:8080/notification';
  topic : string = "/notifications/messages"

  constructor(){
    console.log("Initialize WebSocket Connection");
    let ws = new SockJS(this.webSocketEndPoint);
    this.stompClient = Stomp.over(ws);
    const _this = this;
        _this.stompClient.connect({}, function (frame : any) {
            _this.stompClient.subscribe(_this.topic, function (sdkEvent : any) {
                _this.onMessageReceived(sdkEvent);
            });
        },);
  }

  disconnect() {
      if (this.stompClient !== null) {
          this.stompClient.disconnect();
      }
      console.log("Disconnected");
  }

  onMessageReceived(message : NotificationWebSocket) {
      console.log("Message Recieved from Server :: " + message);
  }
}
```

This code is initialized in a component loaded when the page is loaded

In the backend of spring boot I have the following websocket configuration

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig implements WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
        config.enableSimpleBroker("/notification");
        config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/wigstat");
    }

    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        registry.addEndpoint("/notifications").setAllowedOrigins( "*" ).withSockJS();
    }
}


@Controller
public class WebSockerSender {

    @Autowired
    private NotificationWebSocketAdapter notificationWebSocketAdapter;

    @MessageMapping("/updates")
    @SendTo("/notifications/messages")
    public NotificationWebSocket send(Notification notification) {
        return notificationWebSocketAdapter.fromEntityToWebSocket( notification );
    }
}
```

As you can see it is a super simple configuration that all tutorials shows.

for CORS purpose for normal rest endpoints I have a Cors filter in backend configuration

```
@Component
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
public class CorsFilter implements Filter {

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
        throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletResponse res = (HttpServletResponse) response;
        HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) request;

        res.setHeader( "Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*" );
        res.setHeader( "Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, DELETE, PUT, OPTIONS" );
        res.setHeader( "Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "*" );

        // Just REPLY OK if request method is OPTIONS for CORS (pre-flight)
        if ( req.getMethod().equals("OPTIONS") ) {
            res.setHeader( "Access-Control-Max-Age", "86400" );
            res.setStatus( HttpServletResponse.SC_OK );
            return;
        }

        chain.doFilter( request, response );
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() { }

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) { }
}
```

When I run the front end and I check the console logs i see the following:

[image]

I dont understand why i can not connect with this super simple configuration.

The Rest enpoints defined with logic as rest controllers works perfectly

Thanks in advance

If i change the cors filter or websocket configuration like this

```
res.setHeader( "Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:4200" );
```

and

```
@Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        registry.addEndpoint("/notifications").setAllowedOrigins( "http://localhost:4200" ).withSockJS();
    }
```

I get the same error

**FIX**

[image]

I change the cors filter to this and also add

```
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
        throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletResponse res = (HttpServletResponse) response;
        HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) request;

        String origin = req.getHeader("Origin");
        res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", allowedOrigins.contains(origin) ? origin : "*");
        res.setHeader( "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true" );
        res.setHeader("Vary", "Origin");
        res.setHeader( "Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, DELETE, PUT, OPTIONS" );
        res.setHeader( "Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "*" );

        // Just REPLY OK if request method is OPTIONS for CORS (pre-flight)
        if ( req.getMethod().equals("OPTIONS") ) {
            res.setHeader( "Access-Control-Max-Age", "86400" );
            res.setStatus( HttpServletResponse.SC_OK );
            return;
        }

        chain.doFilter( request, response );
    }
```

.setAllowedOrigins("http://localhost:4200") in the configuration. Now I have to figure out how to configure that for all different environments, not only locally

Comment: the whole problem is explicitly written in the error message. you can't use `allow-origin: *` wildcard pattern here. you should explicitly set what origin can access your endpoint. you can set `http://localhost:4200` here or request->headers->origin and cors error should go away

Comment: the rest of the requests are made with no credentials mode. in this mode wildcard is allowed. but sockjs makes the requests with credentials included, so wildcard cannot be used

Comment: you should add the credentials header also. change origin as described in error and follow other error messages when you get them

Comment: Error stTes clearly that it cannot be a woldcard when credentials are used

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FIX

[image]

I change the cors filter to this and also add

```
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
        throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletResponse res = (HttpServletResponse) response;
        HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) request;

        String origin = req.getHeader("Origin");
        res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", allowedOrigins.contains(origin) ? origin : "*");
        res.setHeader( "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true" );
        res.setHeader("Vary", "Origin");
        res.setHeader( "Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, DELETE, PUT, OPTIONS" );
        res.setHeader( "Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "*" );

        // Just REPLY OK if request method is OPTIONS for CORS (pre-flight)
        if ( req.getMethod().equals("OPTIONS") ) {
            res.setHeader( "Access-Control-Max-Age", "86400" );
            res.setStatus( HttpServletResponse.SC_OK );
            return;
        }

        chain.doFilter( request, response );
    }
```

setAllowedOrigins("http://localhost:4200") in the configuration. Now I have to figure out how to configure that for all different environments, not only locally

Answer (score 0):

FIX

I change the cors filter to this and also add

```
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
        throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletResponse res = (HttpServletResponse) response;
        HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) request;

        String origin = req.getHeader("Origin");
        res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", allowedOrigins.contains(origin) ? origin : "*");
        res.setHeader( "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true" );
        res.setHeader("Vary", "Origin");
        res.setHeader( "Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, DELETE, PUT, OPTIONS" );
        res.setHeader( "Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "*" );

        // Just REPLY OK if request method is OPTIONS for CORS (pre-flight)
        if ( req.getMethod().equals("OPTIONS") ) {
            res.setHeader( "Access-Control-Max-Age", "86400" );
            res.setStatus( HttpServletResponse.SC_OK );
            return;
        }

        chain.doFilter( request, response );
    }
```

.setAllowedOrigins("http://localhost:4200") in the configuration. Now I have to figure out how to configure that for all different environments, not only locally (with @ConfigurationPropeties maybe or adding all origings appart from localhost in a array of strings)